# Joomla Purity iii Navigation Border

Tags: css, templates, joomla, navbar, nav

I have trouble removing the white border-bottom from the standard purity iii navigation list items (both active and hover) . Can any1 familiar with purity iii help me? Thank you.

Here is an example  http://www.taxiinterlaken.ch/Test2/

Comment: i posted a link maybe it helps u

Answer (score 0):

Set 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {box-shadow:none;}

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code (and you can create a code block by indenting with four spaces).